# Lua Scripting Error for Dota 2

Tags: lua

No where else seems to be able to help me so I came here in the hopes that someone can help with with this problem I am having with Lua scripting for Dota2

Here is my broken code:

```
function ApplyDamage(keys)

local caster = keys.caster
local ability = keys.ability
local target = keys.target

ability.level = ability:GetLevel() - 1

local ability_dmg = ability:GetLevelSpecialValueFor( "damage", ability.level )

if caster:HasScepter() then
    ability_dmg = ability:GetSpecialValueFor( "damage_scepter", ability.level )
end

ApplyDamage({victim = target, attacker = caster, damage = ability_dmg, damage_type = ability:GetAbilityDamageType()})
```

end

This is returning the error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDtrg.png

I can't figure out why it is doing this or how I can fix this. Please help.

Comment: How are you calling the function? It seems that whatever you are passing in as an argument does not contain a value associated with *ability.*

Answer (score 0):

You code is not broken per-se.  But the "keys" parameter you pass as an argument does not contain a key "ability".  You must check your call site, not the function itself.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that by calling your function "ApplyDamage" you are overwriting DOTA's global [ApplyDamage function](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Dota_2_Workshop_Tools/Scripting/API/Global.ApplyDamage). Then when you call `ApplyDamage` from inside your function, you are actually calling the function you just defined, not the global one which you probably meant to call. Instead, you should use a name that isn't already used by DOTA, e.g. `damageTarget`.

```
local function damageTarget(keys)
    local caster = keys.caster
    local ability = keys.ability
    local target = keys.target

    ability.level = ability:GetLevel() - 1

    local ability_dmg = ability:GetLevelSpecialValueFor(
        "damage",
        ability.level
    )

    if caster:HasScepter() then
        ability_dmg = ability:GetSpecialValueFor(
            "damage_scepter",
            ability.level
        )
    end

    ApplyDamage{
        victim = target,
        attacker = caster,
        damage = ability_dmg,
        damage_type = ability:GetAbilityDamageType()
    }
end
```